# Cannot download firebase storage files with js loop

Tags: javascript, loops, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the download url of some files of firebase storage with a javascript loop like shown in the code below. It creates the elements correctly but it only assigns a "src" to the second one (in the case of working with 2 files).

```
var photosContainer = document.getElementById('photosContainer');
var photoNumber = firebase.database().ref('main/' + keyParent).child(key + '/number_photos');

photoNumber.on('value', function(snapshot){

  for(var i = 0; i < snapshot.val(); i++){

   var divPhoto = document.createElement('div');
   photosContainer.appendChild(divPhoto);
   var photo = document.createElement('img');
   photo.style.width = '100%';
   divPhoto.appendChild(photo);
   var photosStorage = firebase.storage().ref('main/');
   photosStorage.child(i + key).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      photo.src = url;
   }).catch(function(error) {
     // Handle any errors
     console.log('An error occurred.')
   });
  }
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works by creating an array, adding the urls to the array and then erasing the previous elements and creating the new ones inside array.forEach().

Answer (score 0):

when getDownloadURL() got its file path from Firebase, the "photo.src = url;" is the second element Object.

Comment: know how to fix it?

Comment: To handle the asynchronous request, try the ID of the element: `photo.id= 'imgabc-'+i;
photosStorage.child(i + key).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      document.getElementById('imgabc-'+i).src = url;
   }`

Comment: it doesn't work. I've written console.log inside the loop and another inside the getDownloadURL().then()... and I've seen that the i value is not the same. it doesn't make it in order.